# How to search by 'Added (by email)' va 'Added (by Admin)' for group membership

Tags: civimail, groups

I am trying to find the best way to confirm users are double opted in to a group.  A method I'd like to use is to see who has added themselves versus who was added by an administrator.  I see this in the groups tab on a contact; how can I search by how someone was added to a group?